# Roslyn Source Generator not generating any source in a .net framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, roslyn

Probably a simple learning issue, but I'm attempting to use the new roslyn source generators to automatically generate some source code for .net framework 4.7.2 (mvc is the goal, but I'll be happy if it worked in my test console app).

Here's my code

```
    [Generator]
    public class GenerateCommand : ISourceGenerator
    {
        public const string TestCode = @"
namespace Test
{
    public static class Hello
    {
        public static string World = ""Hi from generated code."";
    }
}";

        public void Initialize(InitializationContext context) { }

        public void Execute(SourceGeneratorContext context)
        {
            context.AddSource("Hint_Hello_World", SourceText.From(TestCode, Encoding.UTF8));
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            var x = Test.Hello.World;  // <-- Refuses to build.
        }
    }
}
```

Package versions are Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp v 3.7.0 (and associated roslyn stuff)

This seems to be about as simple as I can make it and it seems to work if I'm targeting .net core, it's just when I'm trying to add it to a framework project that it does nothing.  No errors, no output messages, just not running or generating source.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET **Core** 5. The `Core` part was removed for marketing purposes to avoid "confusing customers". Despite the marketing talk about unification, it's actually deprecation of .NET Old by moving any APIs that were ever going to be migrated to .NET Core and renaming it .NET 5

Comment: This means that .NET Old generators shouldn't be available in .NET Old projects, as they use an older SDK

Comment: So basically you're saying that the roslyn stuff won't ever work until we upgrade to .net 5?

Comment: Do you think there would be a way to generate the code in a dll that could be imported into a .net old app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**: As of Roslyn 3.8 / Visual Studio 16.8 source generators are no longer behind a preview flag, and should work for any language version or target framework.

Ensure you check out the [Breaking changes](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#breaking-changes) section of the cookbook to address any API differences between preview and release.

---

<s>Currently source generators are gated behind `<langversion>preview</langversion>` as they aren't a released feature, and we don't want customers accidentally using them without realizing it.~~</s>

At release time we'll remove the language version restriction and they'll work on any supported Roslyn compiler, although it will be up to the individual generator authors to ensure that the code they generate is correct for the project options the user has selected.

Comment: I copied OP's sample code into my project, but it fails to build for me as well. I have `LangVersion` set to `preview` in my csproj file, but I can't get any generators to "run".

Comment: @Dave the `preview` flag is no longer required to run generators. You can look at the build logs and make sure your generator is being passed via the `/analyzers:` flag to csc.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit thanks to Chris Sienkiewicz:** Currently source code generators are gated behind the preview language version and thus not available for other .NET versions than .NET 5. This will however change once source code generators are released and stable.

---

**Old Answer:**

Source code generators are a .NET (Core) 5/ C# 9 feature, there is no way to get it to work with .NET Framework (or .NET Core != 5). If you need to generate code at compile time, you have a few options:

1. Use a [T4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019) template
2. Add a [pre-build event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019)
3. Use a NuGet package like [Clarius.TransformOnBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Clarius.TransformOnBuild/)

Comment: The next version of source generators will no longer have the strict tie to language version, at which point the only requirement for use in .NET Framework will be having a compiler new enough to run source generators.

Comment: As @SamHarwell said, this isn't true. We currently require the user opt into generators via a preview language version, but this restriction will be lifted at release time.

Comment: @ChrisSienkiewicz huh, didn't know that. Is that documented somewhere per chance and I just missed it?